# Why reading integers from file into a 2d vector is resulting all values to be zero?

Tags: c++

I am trying to read a matrix of integer values from a text file into a 2d vector.

Input Data:

> 4 5
>
> 0 -0.5 -3 -1 -4
>
> 40 1 1 1 1
>
> 10 -2 -1 1 1
>
> 10 0 1 0 -1

My code:

```
    ifstream InFile("Simplex_EX1.txt");

    if (!InFile.is_open())
        cout << "File could not be opened correctly";

    vector<vector<int>> MyData;
    int Rows, Columns;
    InFile >> Rows >> Columns; // read first line - working

    MyData.resize(Rows);
    for (int i = 0; i < Rows; i++)
        MyData[i].resize(Columns);

    for (int i = 0; i < Rows; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < Columns; j++)
            InFile >> MyData[i][j]; // read the rest - not working

    InFile.close();
```

So I successfully read the first line, hence I resize the vector correctly. However, final vector is just zeros. Could any one tell me what am I doing wrong? Please and thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to read a floating point number `-0.5` into an integer, which fails. Once the stream fails it will not read anything else until the error is cleared.